# Setting onreadystatechange callback to const arrow function w/ parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm following this [guide to ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) and trying to convert the code in step 3 to something that uses const. declarations, however, my readystatechange callback keeps getting called with a 1 readyState.

```
            const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

            const makeRequest = () => {
                console.log('in makeRequest')
                const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (!httpRequest) {
                    alert('problem');
                    return false;
                }
                httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => renderProfile(httpRequest);
                httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/kamranahmedse')
            }

            const renderProfile = (httpRequest) => {
                console.log('in renderProfile')
                if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                        alert('working?');
                    } else {
                        alert('problem')
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(httpRequest)
                }
            }

            submit.addEventListener('click', makeRequest)
```

changing the onreadystate callback to a arrow function did not have any effect. I think the callback is being called immediately since it is not being stored as a reference, but I don't understand how that could be.

Comment: Looks fine to me. It should be getting called at appropriate times. Maybe your expectations of when it should be called are incorrect? If it's getting called with a readyState value... it must be getting called in the correct way.

Comment: that said, what value does changing these to const and arrow functions bring to your codebase?

Comment: You [forgot to send the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

Comment: The modern way to send AJAX is with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: A more modern way to use `XMLHttpRequest` is using `load` and `error` events rather than `.onreadystatechange` - unless you care about ready states other than DONE (which you don't) - but `fetch` is better